# Periodic checking of request status C#

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need a way to periodically check the status of some request using C# every 15 seconds. I will be using Xamarin.Forms, and it would be nice if I didn't have to write any platform specific code.

I need to check the status every 15 seconds for two minutes. If request is rejected or accepted I need the checking to stop and run some other code. What would be the best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, creating a timer would do the thing. Here is an example on how to check a request every 15 seconds for 2 minutes.

```
int twoMinutesCounter = 1; // the value that will reach 120 seconds; 2 minutes = 120 seconds
int fifteenSeconds = 15; // obvious
int secondsElapsed = 1;
// create a timer that ticks every 1 second
DispatcherTimer theTimer = new Timer();
theTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,1); // days, hours, minutes, seconds
// the elapse event. here put your request checking
theTimer.Elapsed += (_, __) => 
{
    // if its 2 minutes then stop the timer
    if (twoMinutesCounter >= 120) 
    {
        // stop the timer to stop checking
        theTimer.Stop();
    }
    // check if its 15 seconds
    if (secondsElapsed >= fifteenSeconds) 
    {
        // here, request to check the status
        // do the checking

        // reset the seconds elapse to check again for 15 seconds
        secondsElapsed = 1;
   }
   secondsElapsed++; // increase seconds elapse
   twoMinutesCounter++; // increase the two minutes counter every seconds
}
// start the timer
theTimer.Start();
```